# How to access string arguments from calldata in external functions? (0.5.X)

Tags: solidity, solc, calldata

With the introduction of `Solc 0.5.X` , parameter memory locations for arrays (and strings/bytes) must be made explicit. For `external` functions, this memory location is required to be specified as `calldata` (as per [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html?highlight=calldata)).

My question is, how to convert the following function to be `0.5.X` compatible and access the properties from within the function body. In addition, what changes (if any) will this have to how we call the method and pass the args?

`0.4.X`

```
function accessTheString(string _uri) 
external {        
    contractString = _uri;
}
```

`0.5.X`

```
function accessTheString(string calldata) 
external {        
    // check for && access the string
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it after just putting the memory location i.e. `calldata` and leaving rest as it is?

Comment: @A.K. I have not. The variable is undeclared so how would the contract know which prop to access? Setting `string calldata _uri` in func args results in compilation error (unexpected token)

Comment: If you add `calldata`, you have to update solidity version in pragma as `0.5.0` and need to use 0.5.0 compiler

Comment: @A.K. Yes I know, this is why I am asking the question

Answer (score 3):

The format is

```
function accessTheString(string calldata _uri) external{        
    string memory contractString= _uri;
}
```

Now, I think you made a mistake while calling the function by without passing string between " ".
You have to call function accessTheString, by passing a string enclosed in " "
ex: accessTheString("hello");

I tested this in remix, and its working

Comment: Hah.. my problem was that I was using solium linter to lint my contracts from vscode. The release was 5 months ago so presumably they dont support 0.5.x yet. D'oh